# What status code should I return for a non AJAX request to an AJAX only URL?

Tags: ajax, http, http-status-codes

If the URL is requested not using AJAX what status code should be returned? 400?

Comment: How do you know how the URL was requested? Ajax or not it's just a URL

Comment: If HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH is equal to XMLHttpRequest in the request header then it's an AJAX request. In Django you can check using request.is_ajax()

Comment: I want to handle non AJAX requests. For example if someone makes a standard GET request to that URL I want to show an error page with the correct status code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not convinced that you're really helping anyone by policing this value. I'd prefer a philosophy of trying to send back useful data in all cases. However, it's not much of a stretch to imagine similar situations where we do need a policy. For example, suppose we have a service that can return JSON or XML depending upon the mime type, perhaps it is  better to return a clear response code if an unexpected mime type is specified.

W3 [say](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html)

> The 4xx codes are intended for cases
>   in which the client seems to have
>   erred, and the 5xx codes for the cases
>   in which the server is aware that the
>   server has erred. It is impossible to
>   distinguish these cases in general, so
>   the difference is only informational.
>
> The body section may contain a
>   document describing the error in human
>   readable form. The document is in MIME
>   format, and may only be in text/plain,
>   text/html or one for the formats
>   specified as acceptable in the
>   request.

And so it seems clear that the response should be a 4xx, it't the client supplying an invalid request. I'd go with 400 BAD REQUEST and make sure that the text returned explains why the request is considered bad.

W3 says for 400: **The request had bad syntax or was inherently impossible to be satisfied**, and that does indeed seem to be the case.

Answer (score 8):

I think `403 Forbidden` ist best.

`501 Not Implemented` does not fit well, because the resource *is* implemented, but just not suited for that kind of request.

`400  Bad Request` ist not a good choice either, because this implies, according to the spec, that "the request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax", which is not the case here.

Comment: Agreed and this seems to be the consensus view. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723548/what-error-to-return-if-method-expects-only-ajax-calls

Answer (score 1):

I'd go `400 Bad Request`, since it has the implication not to retry the request.

Failing that, `418 I'm a teapot`, just to confuse 'em :)